# Perfect loop in OmniGraffle

Tags: drawing, omnigraffle

How can I draw perfect, recursive arrow in Omnigraffle? I'm looking for a cleaner method than the one below.

[image]

Comment: have you tried the Omnigraffle forum? https://discourse.omnigroup.com/c/omnigraffle

Answer (score 1):

You can make one with a circle and a no-stroke line. Let's start with the object that the arrow should be connected to:

[image: start]

Now draw a circle next to the object:

[image: circle]

Now add a line (magnetized to the starting object) with an arrowhead at the start. Draw the line out until the angle of the arrowhead is about right. We're eyeballing it here.

[image: arrow]

Now change the stroke style to "No Stroke":

[image: no stroke]

And you've got a recursive transition arrow!

[image]